# How to manually stop getDisplayMedia stream to end screen capture?

Tags: browser, webrtc, screen-capture, webpage-screenshot, get-display-media

I'm interested in getting a **screenshot** from the user and I'm using the [**`getDisplayMedia`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API) API to capture the user's screen:

```
const constraints = { video: true, audio: false };

if (navigator.mediaDevices["getDisplayMedia"]) {
  navigator.mediaDevices["getDisplayMedia"](constraints).then(startStream).catch(error);
} else {
  navigator.getDisplayMedia(constraints).then(startStream).catch(error);
}
```

When executed, the browser prompts the user if they want to share their display. After the user accepts the prompt, the provided callback receives a MediaStream. For visualization, I'm binding it directly to a  element:

```
  const startStream = (stream: MediaStream) => {
    this.video.nativeElement.srcObject = stream;
  };
```

This is simple and very effective so far. Nevertheless, I'm only interested in a **single frame** and I'd therefore like to manually stop the stream as soon as I've processed it.

What I tried is to remove the `video` element from the DOM, but Chrome keeps displaying a message that the screen is currently captured. So this only affected the video element but not the stream itself:

[image: Screen Capturing in Progress (German)]

I've looked at the [Screen Capture API article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API) but couldn't find any hints on how to stop the stream.

**How do I end the stream properly so that the prompt stops as well?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Rather than stopping the stream itself, you can stop its **tracks**.
Iterate over the tracks using the `getTracks` method and call `stop()` on each of them:

```
stream.getTracks()
  .forEach(track => track.stop())
```

As soon as all tracks are stopped, Chrome's capturing prompt disappears as well.

Answer (score 1):

**start screen capture sample code:**

```
async function startCapture() {
  logElem.innerHTML = "";

  try {
    videoElem.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);
    dumpOptionsInfo();
  } catch(err) {
    console.error("Error: " + err);
  }
}
```

**stop screen capture sample code:**

```
function stopCapture(evt) {
  let tracks = videoElem.srcObject.getTracks();

  tracks.forEach(track => track.stop());
  videoElem.srcObject = null;
}
```

more info: [MDN - Stopping display capture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture)